# Reading output data from a mouse driver

Tags: windows-8, mouse, driver, robotics

I recently disassembled an $8 USD wireless USB mouse I found at the store and got out the hardware and the usb hardware. Where would be a good place to start if I wanted to either

**A-** write my own driver software to use the data from the mouse in the way I'd like to (possibly using the laser for a robot)

-or-

**B-** Get the data the driver outputs without it actually controlling my mouse.(i.e, does the driver output when the laser is inactive and when it is reading?) I feel like this is hard to explain so I'll try my best with another example.. Suppose I want to read in the driver data (Mouse position) and write a program that would translate that into some form of usable information (i.e, read in stream of coordinate, if the stream is stopped, the laser isn't reading anything) but not let the driver actually move the mouse so I still have control over my mouse.

Obviously, B is my preferable approach as it seems easiest but I could be wrong.

Mouse Specs: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/dynex-153-wireless-optical-mouse-gray/2380794.p?id=1218323850772&skuId=2380794

Operating System: Windows 8 64-bit

Resources, suggestions, pointers accepted. (Don't bother pointing me to any other hardware as this was cheap and I got a new mouse so I decided to pull the old one apart to see what I can do with it.)

**EDIT:**
Found [this little bit of information](http://www.dynexproducts.com/support.html), would it be worth modifying the current driver?

**EDIT 2:** Looking around into my drivers, the only two mouse drivers I have are a TouchPad (obviously because I'm on a laptop) and "HID-compliant mouse". I still haven't been able to track down the driver though.

**CURRENT SOLUTION** I'm going to use a java multi-input library to seperate my inputs and hopefully get somewhere. I still need to disable the mouse from moving on the screen somehow though.

Comment: Can you specify an operating system you are developing for?

Comment: oh jeez, wow I forgot that. Windows 8 Preferably.